# не добавляет инпут из формы в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

помогите, не знаю что не так ((

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрос к MySQL неверный.

```
INSERT INTO tasks ('поле_в_которое_записывать_значение') VALUES ('$name')
```

Comment: делал уже так, + у меня там всего одно поле

Comment: Возьмите в кавычки `type="submit"` и `name="Add"`. Так же уберите лишний пробел в `name="Name"`. Напишите `print_r($_POST)` не внутри условия, а в самом начале загрузки страницы. И посмотрите, что вам покажет. Какие параметры будут переданы.

Answer (score 0):

Исправь type="submit" потом name="Add" удали href
Затам сделай print_r($_post) для проверки приходят ли данные из формы, затем выведи $name, оно может быть пустым

Comment: не помогает, оно тупо игнорирует условие if (isset($_POST['Add']))

Comment: я внутри условия написал print_r($_post) и вывел  $name, но ничего не появилось при нажатии

Comment: всем спасибо за помощь, я сделал отдельную кнопку , и с ней все работает)